# React: Array sort not reading state value?

Tags: reactjs

So im working on a pretty basic CRUD app to strengthen my react skills. Right now it's a table of sensors with a state that looks like this:

```
this.state = {
      sensors: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "Temp001DEV",
          device: "Temp",
          temp: "56.4",
          humidity: "33.1",
          active: true
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name: "Humidity002DEV",
          device: "Humidity",
          temp: "",
          humidity: "45.6",
          active: true
        }
      ],
      filterName: "",
      sortBy: "name"
    };
  }
```

(Few demo sensors tossed in there for some fake data).

I also have a sorting function (It's a WIP, my javascript is rusty). That looks like so:

```
 filterSort = () => {
    //Check for filter, then sort
    if (this.state.filterName !== "") {
      const filteredSensors = this.state.sensors.filter(sensor =>
        sensor.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.filterName.toLowerCase())
      );
      console.log(filteredSensors);
      return filteredSensors.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.name < b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if(a.name > b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    } 
    //If no filter exists, just sort
    else {
      return this.state.sensors.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.name < b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if(a.name > b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
        else {
          return 0;
        }
      });;
    }
  };
```

The table is created by mapping through the returned "Filtered/Sorted" array and the table is created that way (Which works). I also have dropdowns and a text input that update the `sortBy` and `filterName` state (Which also works).

Where im running into issues is where i actually call `sort` on the `filteredSensors`. Right now I have `a.name < b.name` etc... (Which does work). But I want it to actually sort based on the state value `sortBy` (Which can be either `name`, `active`, or `device` based on a dropdown I have). However when I try to do something like `const sortVal = this.state.sortBy` and then swap out `.name` for `.sortVal` it doesn't work.

It will just say that the `sortVal` is never used. Any ideas on how to swap out the sorting based off a state value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable called "sortVal" on the elements on the sort function by using dot notation. If you instead use `a[sortVal]` and `b[sortVal]` it will work as it will instead use the variable that sortVal evaluates to (such as humidity) as intented.